# Python Watchdog TypeError：“ bool” object is not iterable

Tags: python, csv, typeerror, watchdog, python-watchdog

I am writing a script to check for any modifications in a given CSV file and am trying to use watchdog to do this. Following the (almost identical) example from [this](http://thepythoncorner.com/dev/how-to-create-a-watchdog-in-python-to-look-for-filesystem-changes/) site, I have the following code:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

def on_deleted(event):
    print(f"what the f**k! Someone deleted {event.src_path}!")

def on_modified(event):
    print(f"hey buddy, {event.src_path} has been modified")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    patterns = ["meetingschedule.csv"]
    ignore_directories = True
    case_sensitive = True
    my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, ignore_directories, case_sensitive)

    my_event_handler.on_deleted = on_deleted
    my_event_handler.on_modified = on_modified

    path = "E:\\COPY\\APPs\\ZoomAutoLog\\Zoommeeting-main\\Ext_Tools\\"
    my_observer = Observer()
    my_observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path)

    my_observer.start()
    print('Watchdog is Monitoring now...')
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Stopping Watchdog...')
        my_observer.stop()
        my_observer.join()
```

When I add a file or directory to watchfolder, I get a TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable. Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 199, in run
    self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 372, in dispatch_events
    handler.dispatch(event)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\watchdog\events.py", line 399, in dispatch
    if match_any_paths(paths,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\watchdog\utils\patterns.py", line 85, in 
match_any_paths
    if _match_path(path, set(included), set(excluded), case_sensitive):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

I have tried changing the type of the go_recursively variable to str and tuple and I get the same error. I've also tried setting the recursive argument directly to True and get the same error. Even I tried to google any relevant info on this error but found none. I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ignore_directories` is the 3rd parameter to `PatternMatchingEventHandler`, not the 2nd.  You're passing that value as `ignore_patterns`, which is expected to be a list.  You can either supply the missing positional param:

```
my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, None, ignore_directories, case_sensitive)
```

Or go keyword:

```
my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, ignore_directories=ignore_directories, case_sensitive=case_sensitive)
```

Comment: Is using case_sensitive= False necessary on Windows...?

Comment: In general, no.  The fact is that "None, False and False" are the default values anyway, so you really only need to supply `patterns`.

Comment: Then why it cannot detect the filesystem changes if I supply "case_sensitive" = True ?